# How do you create a loop of image animations in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I have a series of images I want to display one after the other.  The kicker is they need to have a set time between each image displaying.

here is my code

```
       setTimeout(function() {
            images[0].transitionTo({
                opacity: 1,
                duration: 0
            });
        }, 200);

        setTimeout(function() {
            images[1].transitionTo({
                opacity: 1,
                duration: 0
            });
        }, 400);

        setTimeout(function() {
            images[2].transitionTo({
                opacity: 1,
                duration: 0
            });
        }, 600);
```

..etc (I have about 35 images)

How can express the same thing in a loop?  I'm using the KinetciJS library

I tried using set interval or set timeout but the loop keeps iterating while the timer waits and the array goes out of bounds.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: wow lots of answers already, i'll work though them and let you know how im getting on.. thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
/**
 * Loop images every second.
 */
(function() loopImages() {
   var interval = 1000,
       numOfImage = 35,
       currImage = 1;
   function loop() {
       if (currImage > numOfImage) {
           currImage = 1;
       }
       // display current image in your way.
   }
   setInterval(loop, interval);
})()
```

Comment: what do I set the index to in `images[index].transitionTo({
                    opacity: 1,
                    duration: 0.1
                });`

Comment: With a little fiddling, I got this answer to work.. thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
var numberOfImages = 35;
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
   setTimeout(function() {
        images[i].transitionTo({
            opacity: 1,
            duration: 2
        });
    }, (200 * (i + 1)) );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried something like this but when the loop keeps iterating even when the timeout occurs.  So, when the loop repeats i has already finished iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an incrementor instead of a traditional loop.
Knowing that your image collection is an array, I used the 'currentIteration' variable to
keep track of current index position, and initiated by calling the initAnimation() function. This keeps everything pretty generic and should work regardless of the number of images.

This would allow you to control when the next image animation method is called without being confined to a loop, and could be extended to only be called once the transition is complete if a duration was assigned.

```
var images = ['pic1','pic2','pic3','pic4','pic5'];
var currentIteration = 0;

function initAnimation(){
    animate();
}

function animate(){
    if(currentIteration < image.length){
        window.setTimeout(
        function(){transition()}
        ,800)
    }
}

function transition(){
    images[currentIteration].transitionTo({
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 0
            });
    currentIteration++;
    animate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick (please note this is untested)

```
  var images; // your images
  var idx = 0; //start index
function transition(){
if(idx < images.length){
var image = images[i];
image.transitionTo({
    opacity: 1,
      duration: 0
     });
    idx++;
}else{
 window.clearInterval(intVal);   
}
}
var intVal = window.setInterval(transition,200);
```